# Java failed to lazily initialize a collection with fetch = FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

in my classes I want to have ManyToMany connection between accounts and its favorite rental offers.
for some reason when trying to add something to the favorite set, I'm greeted with failed to lazily init a collection, even with added fetchType.
My enitities:

```
public class Rental {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long rentalId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy = "favoriteRentals"
    )
    private Set<Account> accountFavoriteSet = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID accountId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "fav_rental",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rental_id")
    )
    private Set<Rental> favoriteRentals = new HashSet<>();

// ...

    // method to add to the set of favorites
    public void addFavoriteRental(Rental rental) {
        if (!favoriteRentals.contains(rental)) {
            favoriteRentals.add(rental);
        }
    }
```

In the database the table and columns are showing correctly, just can't ad anything to them.

My test code to check updating existing records:

```
        Optional<Account> accountFav = accountRepository.findById((account1.getAccountId()));
        Optional<Rental> rentalFav = rentalRepository.findById(rental1.getRentalId());

        if (accountFav.isPresent() && rentalFav.isPresent()) {
            accountFav.get().addFavoriteRental(rentalFav.get()); 
            accountRepository.save(accountFav.get());
        }
```

Is my mistake somewhere in the testing logic, or in the jpa mapping?
Error:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ../.entity.Account.favoriteRentals, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

**EDIT:** sorry, forgot to include @ManyToMany in the post

Comment: a. Did you loose ManyToMany annotation in class Account ?
b. Try to mark updating method as Transactional to keep the DB session

Comment: Whoops, forgot to include in the post the annotation, my bad. The @Transactional worked, thanks!